# Is there a way to set the fixed size of a textarea?

Tags: java, javafx, size, scenebuilder

I have a section at the bottom of my main stage, which is the log-section of the software.
That section is just an ordinary TextArea, wrapped in an AnchorPane.
You can resize the height of that Log-AnchorPane from 100px to 400px, which I set as minHeight and maxHeight.
Now I added 2 Buttons in the main stage. These 2 Buttons fold and unfold the Log-Section (I do that by a few lines simple code).

If I fold that section in, the maxHeight of that section is set to zero. And if I unfold it, the height is always the minHeight, which is 100.
Now my question is, is there any elegant way to keep the height of the section, from before I folded that section, if I unfold that section?

I am using java 11.0.2 / jfx 12.0.1, if that does matter.
The values I get are all correct. I can easily get the height of the section.
I already searched for some functions, which can set the height of the area, but it always comes down to the log-area, being the size of the minHeight, instead of the prefHeight.

```
private double lastHeight;

@FXML
private void fold() {
        lastHeight = loggerTab.getHeight();
        loggerTab.setMinHeight(0);
        loggerTab.setMaxHeight(0);
}


@FXML
protected void unfold(){
        loggerTab.setMinHeight(100);
        loggerTab.setPrefHeight(lastHeight);
        loggerTab.setMaxHeight(400);
}`
```

The height of the section after unfolding is the minHeight, instead of the prefHeight.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am curious about what happens if you only set the min and max-height once. Then in your methods, only change the prefheight.

Comment: I think there would be no way to fold the tab then. The size of the log does not care about the prefHeight because there is no restriction (min/max).

Comment: See if any ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464476/javafx-stage-scene-automatic-resize/48466226#48466226) can help.

Comment: Oh yeah they just used a collapsible TitledPane, which looks ugly as hell for me tbh. That's why I created my own "TitledPane". Maybe there is another solution...

Comment: If you want to fit a node a height then you can't allow it to have space. For a TextArea with a height of 400 you have to set Max and Min Height to the same value else it probably fit the pref height but not obligatory. You could also use an Accordion for your problem.

Comment: the problem is probably in the parent of the anchorpane, no way to tell without seeing a [mcve] that you insist on not providing ;)