# Auto-resizing a window based on the content

Tags: java, javafx

Given following FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox spacing="7.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TitledPane text="Title 1">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane expanded="false" text="Title 2">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane expanded="false" text="Title 3">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

and the following Java code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to resize the window automatically, accordingly to how many `TitledPane`s are expanded?

Comment: listen to the state of the titledPanes and adjust the window size as needed .. beware: from a UX perspective it's typically not recommended to change the window size frequently (too much visual noise)

Comment: an idea is to find some properties that indicate a size change of the scene/root, listen to it and call stage.sizeToScene. Couldn't find anything general (layouts have their own rules when/if they _really_ want to be resized) - f.i. a StackPane sizes its content to pref, so it might work to wrap the real content into a stackPane, use that as scene root and listen to size changes of the real content .. might be missing something obvious, feels way to complicated ;)

Comment: @kleopatr Maybe it would be better if I wrapped the `TitledPane`s with a `ScrollPane`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX Stage/Scene automatic resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464476/javafx-stage-scene-automatic-resize)

Comment: Sedrick - Without trying it: does this also respect the animation of the TitledPane? I think not, right? For the rest i have to agree with @kleopatra about three issues with the UX...

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution hacked together in Kotlin. Keep in mind, that this only showcases how you can do it - the `5 * 14` was just me fiddling around to find the right amount...

```kotlin
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.geometry.Insets
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.stage.Stage

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(TestApp::class.java, *args)
}

class TestApp: Application() {
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        val t1: TitledPane
        val t2: TitledPane
        val t3: TitledPane
        VBox().apply {
            fun TitledPane.creatTextArea() {
                content = TextArea().apply {
                    minHeight = 125.0
                    prefHeight = 125.0
                    prefRowCount = 1
                    isWrapText = true
                }
            }
            padding = Insets(14.0)
            children.addAll(
                TitledPane().apply {
                    t1 = this
                    text = "Title 1"
                    creatTextArea()
                },
                TitledPane().apply {
                    t2 = this
                    text = "Title 2"
                    isExpanded = false
                    creatTextArea()
                },
                TitledPane().apply {
                    t3 = this
                    text = "Title 3"
                    isExpanded = false
                    creatTextArea()
                }
            )
        }.let {
            Scene(it)
        }.let {
            primaryStage.apply {
                scene = it
                this.minHeightProperty().bind(this.maxHeightProperty())
                this.maxHeightProperty().bind(t1.heightProperty().add(t2.heightProperty()).add(t3.heightProperty()).add(5  * 14))
            }
        }.show()
    }
}
```