# Changing scenes with Alert JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, view, model

I'm using JavaFX and trying to make a small GUI application where the user can interact with spacetraders.io API.
I've implemented an Alert dialog box when the user attempts to make any transaction (purchase a ship, obtain a loan, purchase goods, sell goods...), and once the user has confirmed their transaction, the stage will be switched to a stage that displays the results of the transaction when shown.

[Correct Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVN23.png)

The Alert dialog box functions fine but the switching of stage presents an issue. When I switch the stage, the full scene is not loaded for some odd reason, the back button is chopped off.

[Chopped Off Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdqsa.png)

When I then click anywhere on the window, the stage is fully shown as in the first image. (all it takes is one click anywhere inside the window).

When I remove the Alert, the stage loads fine. But when I put the same code into an ifPresent lambda, the stage fails to load fully/properly.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure you want to obtain this loan?");
alert.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
    if (response == ButtonType.OK) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        //make title, backbtn, res
        borderPane.setTop(title);
        borderPane.setBottom(backBtn);
        borderPane.setCenter(res);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

I've looked at the docs and I can't seem to figure out why this is the case? Any solutions are welcome?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry, i'm new to SO, is that better?

Comment: well .. not really, missing the _reproducible_ part ;) There seem to be context that you don't provide (f.i. event). So please read the referenced help page and be sure to follow it: the example must be compilable, runnable as-is _and_ demonstrating what's wrong

Comment: Perhaps you should [size the stage to the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464476/javafx-stage-scene-automatic-resize), but, even if that works, it may just be masking the root cause of your issue.

Comment: @jewelsea It did work, however, I'm not sure what the cause of the issue was. I'd like to know of course